# Query with EXISTS-subquery taking about 280 ms in 80 % of cases, and less than 1 ms in 20 % of cases

Tags: query-performance, mariadb-10.3

I noticed a query that seemed to take way too long most of the time, so I investigated it with the Laravel query logger (to get the time and the actual SQL from the query builder).

Excerpt:

```
>>> DB::flushQueryLog(); DB::enableQueryLog(); Company::findAllByNameOrAlias('Frankfurt University of Applied Sciences'); DB::getQueryLog()
=> [
     [
       "query" => "select * from `companies` where (`name` = ? or exists (select * from `company_aliases` where `companies`.`id` = `company_aliases`.`company_id` and `name` = ?)) and `companies`.`deleted_at` is null",
       "bindings" => [
         "Frankfurt University of Applied Sciences",
         "Frankfurt University of Applied Sciences",
       ],
       "time" => 278.46,
     ],
   ]
>>> DB::flushQueryLog(); DB::enableQueryLog(); Company::findAllByNameOrAlias('Frankfurt University of Applied Sciences'); DB::getQueryLog()
=> [
     [
       "query" => "select * from `companies` where (`name` = ? or exists (select * from `company_aliases` where `companies`.`id` = `company_aliases`.`company_id` and `name` = ?)) and `companies`.`deleted_at` is null",
       "bindings" => [
         "Frankfurt University of Applied Sciences",
         "Frankfurt University of Applied Sciences",
       ],
       "time" => 0.72,
     ],
   ]
>>> DB::flushQueryLog(); DB::enableQueryLog(); Company::findAllByNameOrAlias('Frankfurt University of Applied Sciences'); DB::getQueryLog()
=> [
     [
       "query" => "select * from `companies` where (`name` = ? or exists (select * from `company_aliases` where `companies`.`id` = `company_aliases`.`company_id` and `name` = ?)) and `companies`.`deleted_at` is null",
       "bindings" => [
         "Frankfurt University of Applied Sciences",
         "Frankfurt University of Applied Sciences",
       ],
       "time" => 0.67,
     ],
   ]
>>> DB::flushQueryLog(); DB::enableQueryLog(); Company::findAllByNameOrAlias('Frankfurt University of Applied Sciences'); DB::getQueryLog()
=> [
     [
       "query" => "select * from `companies` where (`name` = ? or exists (select * from `company_aliases` where `companies`.`id` = `company_aliases`.`company_id` and `name` = ?)) and `companies`.`deleted_at` is null",
       "bindings" => [
         "Frankfurt University of Applied Sciences",
         "Frankfurt University of Applied Sciences",
       ],
       "time" => 298.88,
     ],
   ]
```

Notice the query times.

The use case: I am looking for companies by name, but we want to be able to specify aliases that identify the same company. The `companies` table has an index on name, and the `company_aliases` table has an index on name, too. `company_aliases.company_id` has a foreign key constraint referencing `companies.id`.

Cherry on top: The table `company_aliases` is empty.
EXPLAIN for the above query:

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | companies | ALL | companies_name_index | NULL | NULL | NULL | 241068 | Using where |
| 2 | MATERIALIZED | company_aliases | ref | company_aliases_company_id_foreign,company_aliases_name_index | company_aliases_name_index | 1022 | const | 1 | Using index condition |

Leaving out the `company_aliases` table and searching in `companies` only, gives sub 1 ms run times consistently.

```
>>> DB::flushQueryLog(); DB::enableQueryLog(); Company::where('name', 'Frankfurt University of Applied Sciences')->first(); DB::getQueryLog()
=> [
     [
       "query" => "select * from `companies` where `name` = ? and `companies`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1",
       "bindings" => [
         "Frankfurt University of Applied Sciences",
       ],
       "time" => 0.84,
     ],
   ]
>>> DB::flushQueryLog(); DB::enableQueryLog(); Company::where('name', 'Frankfurt University of Applied Sciences')->first(); DB::getQueryLog()
=> [
     [
       "query" => "select * from `companies` where `name` = ? and `companies`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1",
       "bindings" => [
         "Frankfurt University of Applied Sciences",
       ],
       "time" => 0.95,
     ],
   ]
>>> DB::flushQueryLog(); DB::enableQueryLog(); Company::where('name', 'Frankfurt University of Applied Sciences')->first(); DB::getQueryLog()
=> [
     [
       "query" => "select * from `companies` where `name` = ? and `companies`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1",
       "bindings" => [
         "Frankfurt University of Applied Sciences",
       ],
       "time" => 0.83,
     ],
   ]
>>> DB::flushQueryLog(); DB::enableQueryLog(); Company::where('name', 'Frankfurt University of Applied Sciences')->first(); DB::getQueryLog()
=> [
     [
       "query" => "select * from `companies` where `name` = ? and `companies`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1",
       "bindings" => [
         "Frankfurt University of Applied Sciences",
       ],
       "time" => 0.73,
     ],
   ]
>>> DB::flushQueryLog(); DB::enableQueryLog(); Company::where('name', 'Frankfurt University of Applied Sciences')->first(); DB::getQueryLog()
=> [
     [
       "query" => "select * from `companies` where `name` = ? and `companies`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1",
       "bindings" => [
         "Frankfurt University of Applied Sciences",
       ],
       "time" => 0.6,
     ],
   ]
>>> DB::flushQueryLog(); DB::enableQueryLog(); Company::where('name', 'Frankfurt University of Applied Sciences')->first(); DB::getQueryLog()
=> [
     [
       "query" => "select * from `companies` where `name` = ? and `companies`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1",
       "bindings" => [
         "Frankfurt University of Applied Sciences",
       ],
       "time" => 0.9,
     ],
   ]
>>> DB::flushQueryLog(); DB::enableQueryLog(); Company::where('name', 'Frankfurt University of Applied Sciences')->first(); DB::getQueryLog()
=> [
     [
       "query" => "select * from `companies` where `name` = ? and `companies`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1",
       "bindings" => [
         "Frankfurt University of Applied Sciences",
       ],
       "time" => 0.86,
     ],
   ]
>>> DB::flushQueryLog(); DB::enableQueryLog(); Company::where('name', 'Frankfurt University of Applied Sciences')->first(); DB::getQueryLog()
=> [
     [
       "query" => "select * from `companies` where `name` = ? and `companies`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1",
       "bindings" => [
         "Frankfurt University of Applied Sciences",
       ],
       "time" => 0.64,
     ],
   ]
>>> DB::flushQueryLog(); DB::enableQueryLog(); Company::where('name', 'Frankfurt University of Applied Sciences')->first(); DB::getQueryLog()
=> [
     [
       "query" => "select * from `companies` where `name` = ? and `companies`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1",
       "bindings" => [
         "Frankfurt University of Applied Sciences",
       ],
       "time" => 0.53,
     ],
   ]
>>> DB::flushQueryLog(); DB::enableQueryLog(); Company::where('name', 'Frankfurt University of Applied Sciences')->first(); DB::getQueryLog()
=> [
     [
       "query" => "select * from `companies` where `name` = ? and `companies`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1",
       "bindings" => [
         "Frankfurt University of Applied Sciences",
       ],
       "time" => 0.47,
     ],
   ]
>>> DB::flushQueryLog(); DB::enableQueryLog(); Company::where('name', 'Frankfurt University of Applied Sciences')->first(); DB::getQueryLog()
=> [
     [
       "query" => "select * from `companies` where `name` = ? and `companies`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1",
       "bindings" => [
         "Frankfurt University of Applied Sciences",
       ],
       "time" => 0.55,
     ],
   ]
>>> DB::flushQueryLog(); DB::enableQueryLog(); Company::where('name', 'Frankfurt University of Applied Sciences')->first(); DB::getQueryLog()
=> [
     [
       "query" => "select * from `companies` where `name` = ? and `companies`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1",
       "bindings" => [
         "Frankfurt University of Applied Sciences",
       ],
       "time" => 0.53,
     ],
   ]
>>> DB::flushQueryLog(); DB::enableQueryLog(); Company::where('name', 'Frankfurt University of Applied Sciences')->first(); DB::getQueryLog()
=> [
     [
       "query" => "select * from `companies` where `name` = ? and `companies`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1",
       "bindings" => [
         "Frankfurt University of Applied Sciences",
       ],
       "time" => 0.66,
     ],
   ]
>>> DB::flushQueryLog(); DB::enableQueryLog(); Company::where('name', 'Frankfurt University of Applied Sciences')->first(); DB::getQueryLog()
=> [
     [
       "query" => "select * from `companies` where `name` = ? and `companies`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1",
       "bindings" => [
         "Frankfurt University of Applied Sciences",
       ],
       "time" => 0.79,
     ],
   ]
>>> DB::flushQueryLog(); DB::enableQueryLog(); Company::where('name', 'Frankfurt University of Applied Sciences')->first(); DB::getQueryLog()
=> [
     [
       "query" => "select * from `companies` where `name` = ? and `companies`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1",
       "bindings" => [
         "Frankfurt University of Applied Sciences",
       ],
       "time" => 0.84,
     ],
   ]
```

A search in `company_aliases` is as fast as a search in `companies`, so it's a viable workaround to query `companies` and, if no result was found, query `company_aliases`. The total query time is still below 2 ms. Essentially, I am just moving the lazy evaluation of the `OR` into my PHP code. But this shouldn't be faster than executing the same logic entirely in the DB.

What's the reason?

Comment: Please test the query execution time after OPTIMIZE TABLE. Does the execution time "jumps" again?

Comment: @Akina It didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"A search in company_aliases is as fast as a search in companies, so it's a viable workaround to query companies and, if no result was found, query company_aliases. The total query time is still below 2 ms. Essentially, I am just moving the lazy evaluation of the OR into my PHP code. But this shouldn't be faster than executing the same logic entirely in the DB."
That's not the same logic. The query is saying give me the rows in `companies` that either have the same name as this value or can be found in `company_aliases` with this value. There's nothing which tells it to stop when it finds a match.

You can expand the `OR` condition manually:

```
select * 
from  `companies` 
where  `name` = ? 
and    `companies`.`deleted_at` is null
union all
select * 
from  `companies` 
where  exists (select null 
               from   `company_aliases` 
               where  `companies`.`id` = `company_aliases`.`company_id` 
               and    `name` = ?
              )
and    `companies`.`deleted_at` is null
and   ( `name` <> ? or `name` is null)
```

This should give you a plan which uses an index on `companies.name` to satisfy the first part, and it should use an index on `company_aliases.name` followed by a loop to `companies` based on `id` for the second part. Assuming those indexes exist, you should be fine.

Comment: Of course you are correct with your analysis of the query behavior. Your query actually is using the index on `companies.name`. Now I see that it is irrelevant, if `companies` contains the searched name -- so it does not make sense to use the index on `companies.name`. Very nice answer!